# AngularJS nested directive not getting evaluated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've just begun creating Angular directives (I'm new to the framework, as well), but am running into issues wherein a nested directive seems to be ignored. The basis for my directives' code is [UI Bootstrap's](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs) "tabs" and "pane" directives.

The gist is that I want to be able to compile a list of "components" inside a "layout". Ultimately, there should also be an attribute on each "component" tag that will instruct the layout to render content from some known template location. For now, however, I can't even get the "link" function inside the component directive to fire, even though I've got two components in my template.

Here's a plunk of my situation:

http://plnkr.co/edit/K4n2Mx3kZyvVYGDyJ7t9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mis-using `ngTransclude` by placing it inside of `ngRepeat`.  It's sort of a chicken/egg situation where since there's nothing to repeat over, nothing gets transcluded.

Also, since you're specifying components in HTML, you don't even need `ngRepeat` in your template.

http://plnkr.co/edit/aYjdd4skbKC3FEM3lCfY?p=preview

```
template:
  '<section class="layout">' +
    '<h4>Before all components</h4>' +
    '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
    '<h4>After all components</h4>' +
  '</section>'
```

Comment: D'oh, looking back at the code for UI Bootstrap, they indeed have the ngTransclude directive outside of their loop (they're just using the ngRepeat directive to display a list of tabs above each pane). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

When you use ng-repeat, it creates a new scope and it makes you ng-transclude not in the right scope for injecting the transclusion.

So when you remove the ng-repeat, you get the rendered components.

Now, in order to control the layout, you can either add the elements to the controllers like you do with their scope, and then layout them accordingly in the controller:

```
// inside the controller
this.addComponentElement = function (componentElement) {
  componentElements.push(componentElement);
};
// watch for array changes and handle layout
```

Or, you can use the transclude function in the compile + link combination to get a reference to the transcluded dom and manipulate its layout:

```
  compile:function(telement, tAttrs, transcludeFn){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
      transcludeFn(scope, function(transcludedDom){
        // layout the transcludedDom
      })
    }
```